# Java 8 zoned dates conversion

Tags: java, date

I have one question about zones in java. 
I have a user case when user can set time zone and some schedule. For example run task on Mondays and Sundays in 11pm with timezone America/Los_Angeles.
If my server time zone is UTC+0:00 I have a problem how to detect a day of week and new time correctly (it will be about Tuesday and Monday on 6am). So my question is how to run user tasks correctly according to server timezone and user timezone.

**Update**

I have a cron expression where I set hours, minutes and day of week.
When user creates a new task he can set custom timezone(for example to run task on mondays 11pm with custom timezone UTC-7:00)
So if my understanding is right I need to convert his hour setting (11pm) to corresponding server time. So if my server timezone is UTC+3:00 I need to convert 11pm to 9am and it will be not Monday (but Tuesday) on my server. Then if I will run cron on Tuesday 9am it will look to user like task runs on 11pm on Monday. Is my approach correct? I hope you understand my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So can you tell us what the problem is? Can you show us your code? The system clock is always at UTC so there is no reason there has to be a problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I edited my question

Comment: You have to convert the time and day of the week together. Note with daylight savings, you can't just calculate it once and assume this is always right. You have to calculate the next time and add a task to run at that time. e.g. if they chose 1 AM in New-York this will be 21:00 UTC-4 and 20:00 UTC-5 at different times of the year.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Count in milliseconds since the epoch.

The long answer:
First, it is very important to understand how computer time works. I would recommend [this article](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php)., but the gist is, that everything is computed since the epoch, 1.1.1970. Second, I figured an example will tell you more than 1000 words:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-10-20T11:34:57+02:00[Europe/Zurich]"); // UTC + 2
long millisEurope = dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
System.out.println(millisEurope); // 1476956097000

dateTime = dateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")); // UTC - 7
long millisAmerica = dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
System.out.println(millisAmerica); // 1476988497000

// The difference between UTC + 2 and UTC - 7  == -9
System.out.println((millisEurope - millisAmerica) / 1000 / 60 / 60);
```

The [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) will always use UTC (+ 0) plus the defined time zone.

**EDIT** (after the update):
Yes, if you get the time and time zone set by the user, you would have to convert it to your own time zone to be executed on the same point in time.

Answer (score 0):

The time zone setting of your server’s operating system and JVM should be irrelevant to your programming. Both can change at any moment, *during* runtime, so do not rely on it. **Always specify the desired/expected time zone** in the optional argument to the various date-time methods.

Be aware that you cannot schedule time-zone-sensitive moments far in advance. Politicians are notorious for often changing the time zone definitions, sometimes with very little advance notice.

If you want to set an alarm for the next Monday at 11 AM in the context of the user’s time zone, first you need the user’s time zone. You may be able to detect a default time zone, but ultimately the only reliable way is to ask the user for their desired/expected time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Keep the alarm’s day-of-week as a `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
DayOfWeek alarmDow = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ;
```

Keep the alarm’s time-of-day as a `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime alarmTimeOfDay = LocalTime.parse( "11:00:00" );
```

This class lacks a date and lacks any offset-from-UTC or time zone. So it has no meaning until you adjust into a time zone.

Keep the alarm’s time zone as a `ZoneId`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

With those parts in hand, you can schedule the alarm.

Get the current moment as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Apply the desired time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = instant.atZone( z );
```

To determine the future moment of the alarm, use the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface to manipulate date-time values. The class [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (note the plural `s`) provides implementations. First extract a date-only value, as we will be assigning the alarm’s `LocalTime` as the time-of-day.

```
LocalDate today = zdtNow.toLocalDate();
LocalDate dateOfNextOrSameDow = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.withNextOrSame( alarmDow ) );
```

Apply the desired time-of-day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtAlarm = ZonedDateTime.of( dateOfNextOrSameDow , alarmTimeOfDay , z ) ;
```

This particular alarm date-time may have already passed earlier today. So test. If so, add a week to get the next occurrence of the desired day-of-week.

```
if( zdtAlarm.isBefore( zdtNow ) ) {  // If already passed…
    zdtAlarm = zdtAlarm.plusWeeks( 1 );  // …go to next day-of-week occurrence.
}
```